# Click a tag inside tooltipster

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltipster

I have tootipster with custom html

Here is html

```
<div id="a1" class ="hidden">
        <div class="popover-heading"><%= _("Välj ditt språk") %></div>
        <div class="popover-body">
          <div>
            <a href="#" data-lang="no">
            <%= image_tag "flags/123.png", :class => "flag-image" %> Norsk
            </a>
          </div>
          <div>
            <a href="#" data-lang="de">
            <%= image_tag "flags/122.png", :class => "flag-image" %> Deutsch
            </a>
          </div>
          <div>
            <a href="#" data-lang="nl">
            <%= image_tag "flags/131.png", :class => "flag-image" %> Nederlands
            </a>
          </div>
          <div>
            <a href="#" data-lang="es">
            <%= image_tag "flags/142.png", :class => "flag-image" %> Español
            </a>
          </div>
          <div>
            <a href="#" data-lang="dk">
            <%= image_tag "flags/151.png", :class => "flag-image" %> Dansk
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

And here is js code, how I show it in tooltipster

```
 $(".languages").tooltipster({
    trigger: "custom",
    triggerOpen: {
      mouseenter: true
    },
    triggerClose: {
      click: false,
      scroll: true
    },
    contentAsHTML: true,
    placement: "auto",
    autoClose: false,
    content: $("#a1").html()
  });
```

I need to click a tag in tootipster content

I tried it like this

```
 $("#a1").on("click", "a", function() { 
    let lang = $(this).data("lang");
    window.location = "http://flysmarter."+lang;
  });
```

But it not works.
How can i click it?

Comment: '$(".languages")' is referring to which elements? Cannot see '.languages' class anywhere in the code.

Comment: `'$(".languages")'` is just a tag I click to get tooltipster @PrachiMishra

Answer (score 1):

You should set the tooltipster `interactive` option to `true` to be able to click inside it.

```
$(".languages").tooltipster({
     trigger: "custom",
         triggerOpen: {
         mouseenter: true
     },
     triggerClose: {
         click: false,
         scroll: true
     },
    contentAsHTML: true,
    placement: "auto",
    autoClose: false,
    content: $("#a1").html(),
    interactive: true
});
```

Comment: This. Much appreciated - you saved my day!

Answer (score 0):

Please correct the syntax and try again:

Current Code:

```
$("#a1").on("click", "a", function() { 
    let lang = $(this).data("lang");
    window.location = "http://flysmarter."+lang;
  });
```

Corrected Code:

```
$("#a1").on("click", "a", function() { 
    var lang = $(this).data("lang");
    window.location = "http://flysmarter."+lang;
  });
```

Comment: '<div id="a1" class ="hidden">' . How are you clicking on something that is hidden?